# Validator extended to handle domain objects / entities

Tags: php, object-oriented, validation

I started improving my validator library even more, and I think I'm at the last final element (domain object / entity validations) before I can gladly say that my Validator library is completely done and it supports all of it.

[Here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/54799/39625) you can see that my validator can already deal with regular variable inputs or non-entity inputs (certain forms for example).

I started figuring out how I could extend my validator to create domain object validators and here is my attempt.

Could anybody review it and see if you find any room for improvements and give constructive feedback?

**User**

```
class User
{
    public $name;
    public $email;
    public $age;
}
```

**UserValidator**

```
class UserValidator extends Validator
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $rules['name']  = [new MaxChars(20), new Alpha(true)];
        $rules['email'] = [new Email()];
        $rules['age']   = [new Numeric(), new Between(13, 17)];

        $this->setRule('name',  $rules['name']);
        $this->setRule('email', $rules['email']);
        $this->setRule('age',   $rules['age']);
    }

    public function validate(User $user)
    {
        $this->errors = [];

        parent::validate('name',  $user->name);
        parent::validate('email', $user->email);
        parent::validate('age',   $user->age);

        return empty($this->errors);
    }
}
```

**Validator**

```
class Validator
{
    protected $rules  = [];
    protected $errors = [];

    public function getErrors($rulename = null)
    {
        if ($rulename) {
            return isset($this->errors[$rulename]) ? $this->errors[$rulename] : [];
        }

        return $this->errors;
    }

    public function setRule($name, Array $rules, $required = true)
    {
        $this->rules[$name]['rules'] = $rules;

        switch (true) {
            case ($required === true):
                $this->rules[$name]['required'] = 'Must not be null or empty.';
                break;
            case ($required === false):
                $this->rules[$name]['required'] = false;
                break;
            default:
                $this->rules[$name]['required'] = $required;
                break;
        }
    }

    public function validate($rulename, $input)
    {
        if ($this->rules[$rulename]['required']) {
            if (empty($input)) {
                $this->errors[$rulename][] = $this->rules[$rulename]['required'];
            }

            foreach ($this->rules[$rulename]['rules'] as $rule) {
                if (!$rule->check($input)) {
                    $this->errors[$rulename][] = $rule->getError();
                }
            }
        } elseif (!empty($input)) {
            foreach ($this->rules[$rulename]['rules'] as $rule) {
                if (!$rule->check($input)) {
                    $this->errors[$rulename][] = $rule->getError();
                }
            }
        }

        return isset($this->errors[$rulename]);
    }
}
```

**Example**

```
$user        = new User();
$user->name  = 'John Doe';
$user->email = 'john@doe.com';
$user->age   = 13;

$uv = new UserValidator();

$uv->validate($user)); //true
$uv->getErrors());     //empty array
```

Comment: I think it's a bit of an overkill to have whole objects  for `Alpha` or `Numeric`, don't you?

Comment: Whats that [ ] around the instance? [new something]

Comment: @HassanAlthaf Shorthand for arrays. `[]` equals `array()`.

Comment: So what happens when he does that?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha No. This is an objected oriented library. My validator only works with rule objects that implement the IRule interface. If I want to add/make a new rule I don't have to modify my Validator class itself, I just have to create a new rule class and pass it through, making my validation library modular.

Comment: @KidDiamond In my validators, I just pass in callables to the validator class. Not **everything** is an object. This isn't Java.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha So how would you add support for a new rule in your class? By modifying the class itself? Whether this is Java or not, having a class that accepts callable methods that it contains is not OO. And I chose the OO route.

Comment: `public function bindRule($field, callable $validator)` where `$validator` is a callable that takes one argument, and returns `true` or `false` based on whether that element passes whatever validation rule you want. For example: `$validator->bindRule("some_required_field", function($field) { return !empty($field); });` The validator then iterates all of the callables and run them in order. One fails, the field fails. Less overhead than making a full fledged class for each validation rule, just as flexible and powerful.

Comment: Yes, that would be a good option as well. But I think it boils down to personal preference and if you're willing to have that overhead or not.

Comment: Are you expecting future require rules? Or are you using the `switch (true)` for some other reason? I don't see why a switch would take precedence over a conditional here.

Comment: @AlexL Purely for better readability (for me). I don't like how `elseif`s look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coding-wise it looks pretty good. Consistent naming convention and code style, no apparent security vulnerabilities (assuming your Rule classes do what I expect them to do).

Let's talk about approach and scale.

### Scale

It doesn't really make sense for you to write a validator for each Domain Object you create! What if you have 50 Domain Objects, will you write an *extra* 50 classes just for validation?

### Approach

As a result of the above, your `UserValidator` class is very highly tightly coupled with the `User` object, it knows about the structure of the `User` object, making it *useless* for reuse (Unless, of course, you find another project with the exact same `User` object).

### A better approach?

For starters, you should ask yourself *what are you validating?*

Let's differentiate between two possible "validations":

1. Business rule validation - "User chose this city and this country, does it make sense?" or "User said he was born in 2012, does it make sense?"
2. Data-integrity validation - "User already exists in the database" or "Username should contain between 3-20 characters".

Business rule validation belongs in the **Domain Object** itself. (i.e. the `User` object directly). While your data-integrity checks should be done by the RDBM.

More often than not, the RDBM (which is usually MySQL when talking about PHP) is not capable of doing all of that (which is why moving away to a better RDBM is encouraged), in which case those things **also** need to happen at the Domain Object level.

#### TL;DR

It's the job of the domain object to validate itself. It's the job of the storage manager (the database) to make sure the data is correct from the constraints point of view.

The validator class ends up (usually) as a utility class, which is nice to have, but unneeded for an actual project.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused now. So I could use my validation library just for forms in my controller. And have setters in my domain object that do the business rule validation, and since I'm using MySQL data integrity validation would happen there too. But what if I have a field in a form that's supposed to check if the value isn't already in the database? The form submit should not validate and return with an error stating that it already exists. But since the validation that checks for that will be in my domain object, how would I link it up with my form validation in my controller?

Comment: The database has the ability to induce `UNIQUE` constraints. You just need to catch the exception thrown by PDO.

Comment: Okay, so the scenario would be: Form validation in my controller. After form inputs have passed validation, the values will be set to my domain object `User`, this object will be sent to my `UserDAO` object to try and persist it. If let's say the email already exists, catch the PDO exception and return it to my form validator, re-display the form and output the error that the input must be unique. That's right?

Comment: [let's continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor)

Answer (score 4):

I disagree with @Madara Uchiha on a several points.

1. If you couple business rule validations to the domain object, you cannot apply different business rules to the same domain object.

   Never assume you will only have one set of business rules. By creating validators outside the domain object, you give yourself the flexibility of creating whole different swaths of business rules without touching the domain layer.

   Basically, by the time you go to save a domain object to a database or other repository it should be completely valid from a business rule AND storage perspective. This allows you to communicate problems to the user in a manor that allows them to correct their mistake. If you let a SQL error propagate up the call stack and result in a 500 Internal Server Error, you as a programmer have not done your due diligence when validating data.

   Now I could see a case for separating the storage validations from the business rules. Maybe you start out persisting your domain objects in a database, but later you move to a RESTfull web service. The web service may have different basic data validations, which you can then swap out for a different validator while keeping your existing business rule validations.
2. I disagree that this solution doesn't scale. Quite the opposite actually. It scales *very* well. Mashing your validations into the domain object is what doesn't scale. Changing the storage mechanism or needing to apply different categories of business rules gets complicated when your domain objects validate themselves. Domain objects should be mere boxes containing data. The decision of whether that data is correct is wholly out of scope for the domain object, in my opinion.
3. The storage manager should have absolutely *no* validations. It should accept a domain object, attempt to persist it and throw an exception if anything goes wrong.

Really, all of my objections are related to this tenet of software engineering, and especially object oriented programming: **Do one thing, and do it well.**

Putting validations into your domain objects means they are serving a dual purpose: Hold data from a storage medium AND ensuring it is valid. Do one thing and do it well. The domain object should hold data. The validation layer should ensure things are valid.

Putting validations into your storage manager means it is serving a dual purpose in the same manor. You should be able to swap out one layer for another with minimal refactoring. If you have to copy and paste of rewrite lots of code, then your application needs additional layers with looser coupling.

Comment: Besides your disagreement, what you think about my code?

Comment: I think it is a good approach, though I am a tad biased since I submitted an answer to your previous code review. :)

Comment: True, but I was just wondering since I left out your rule builder idea in my version. Other then that, I'm hearing so many different approaches when it comes to domain object validation. I guess at the end of the day I'll have to look at everything side by side and decide myself which way  attracts me the most.

Comment: The lack of a rule builder is not a show stopper. And yes, you'll have to weigh the different approaches and go with the one that fits your needs. There are many ways to solve this problem.

Comment: You shouldn't return a 500 error to the user when the database can't save his invalid data, you should catch the exception, and give a useful error back. Also, when would you need a different set of business rules?